# Is data fetching from cache firebase flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I'm trying to read all document name from firebase. i already fetch in app starts.
I try to fetch data from cache but when I print it shows it "IsFromCache = false"

```
    cf.QuerySnapshot query = await cf.FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('authid')
        .get(cf.GetOptions(source: cf.Source.cache));
        print(query.docs);
        print('Cache :: ${query.metadata.isFromCache}');
```

prints:

```
[Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot']
Cache :: false
```

Comment: And what's the value of `cf.Source.cache`?  Try hard coding it and edit the question so we can all see what this query actually does.  On Stack Overflow, it's better to show complete examples that don't depend on variables we can't see.

Comment: i'm just tying the know the existing document names